Automate sorting list of dates by day instead of chronologically, microsoft excel
I work at a company who sends out birthday cards to our clients on their birthdays. Every month we grab all of the birthdays which happen during the oncoming month and place them into different excel sheets based on which salesperson the client interacts with. We try to send the cards out one week in advance so they arrive close to the client's actual birthdate. In order to do this, I was looking to sort the birthdays of our clients by day so that I could see which letters I need to prepare this week. However, excel will only allow you to sort chronologically (by year) meaning that the oldest dates come first regardless of their birthday's position in the month.
I've had luck with using the =Day command, copying it to the individual rows (in a different column) and then sorting the entire list by that.
However, this job is going to be taken over by one of our older employees and when I tried explaining this to her, she couldn't follow my instructions. I'd like to be able to set up a script to automate this, so she only has to run a short script to get the same result.
I'm hoping to find a solution to this.
I set up a script using the record feature of excel to create a new column of data which corresponds to the days in the month using the "=day" command, and then sort the entire table based on that data. However, when I attempt to use the script it will create the new column of data, but it won't sort the table. I'm still pretty new to coding, so I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I'd appreciate any help you can provide nonetheless.
Another thing I noticed is that if I use =day on an empty cell (the lists of birthdays are different lengths) it will return with "0", which when sorted will go to the top of the document. I've attempted to work around this problem using an "=if" command combined with an "=day"
I've included the script below.
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Set range L2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("L2").setFormulaLocal("=IF(B2=\"\",\"\",DAY(B2))");
    // Paste to range L2:L100 on selectedSheet from range L2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("L2:L100").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("L2"),     ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Sort the range range L2:L100 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("L2:L100").getSort().apply([{ key: 0, ascending: true }], false, false,    ExcelScript.SortOrientation.rows);
}


By day is chronological...

You should start by creating a new column that just contains the number of days from the start of the year.
=B2-7-DATE(YEAR(B2-7),1,1)

Then you can sort based on that column.
